# How to use Javadoc for project having different achitrecture recursively?

Tags: java, javadoc, command-prompt

I have a java project having different modules in it. When I navigate to specific module, I see my source java files are in different directories like - com/test/src OR com/test/main/src
 OR com/main/resource/core etc.

The problem is, I can't go in each and every parent directory and run javadoc to get output.
I tried to use javadoc with -subpackages to fetch recursively all the files but failed. I also tried to get all source files using dir /s /n *.java but it couldn't help really.

What I want is - is it possible to fetch out all the source files recursively and generate javadoc for the same ? like kind of batch file which first find the source and give output to javadoc to generate the docs ??
Also, please let me know if any tool is available to achieve this instead of command prompt.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you use an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse then you can generate the Javadoc for every file in an entire project, across several packages, just by selecting the relevant menu item from the Tools menu. For large projects, an IDE really is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out how to do this using IDE.